# Javascript: Problems getting cookies to main part

Tags: javascript, cookies, greasemonkey, userscripts

Hello everybody i have a question about javascript based userscript using cookies.
For the first part i used a pretty standard fuction:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days,domain) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+domain+"; path=/";}
```

and later on when i try to call the function:

```js
createCookie('ppkcookie',Hours + ":" +Minutes,2,".examplesite.com/")
```

This code works fine but it's only for the specific site its extracted from sub.examplesite.com and i need it as output for www.examplesite.com

I've looked through mountains of posts but i cant figure out how to edit the function that i could add the domain easily.

Is there anyone that could tell me what i'm doing wrong because i tried like 20 different versions of code but nothing seems to fix this problem.

Comment: You can't allocate cookies to a different site. The reason is security

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and possibly modify a cookie with a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749907/how-can-i-access-and-possibly-modify-a-cookie-with-a-userscript)

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is set using the following syntax

```
name=value; expires=Sat, 03 Dec 2016 03:12:25 GMT; domain=.domain.com; path=/
```

What your code is outputting is

```
name=value; expires=Sat, 03 Dec 2016 03:12:25 GMT.domain.com; path=/
```

createCookie function changed as follows

```
function createCookie(name,value,days,domain) {
    // add the following to set domain correctly
    domain = domain ? "; domain=" + domain : "";
    // note, you should also "escape" the value
    value = escape(value);
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+domain+"; path=/";
}
```