# How can I access and possibly modify a cookie with a userscript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, userscripts

A corporate website, which I happen to access often, uses a Basic Auth which triggers a user/pass dialogue. My password manager (LastPass) is unable to fill it. So I want to use a userscript to inject a login form, which is fillable by LastPass.

To test the injected form `onsubmit` function, in  the Firefox Web Console I ran:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://someweb.com/login.do", false);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));
request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", navigator.userAgent);
request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=*****");
request.send();
```

`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` would be retrieved from the filled form.

Everything works as expected, except that I have to retrieve the `JSESSIONID` session cookie. The cookie is sent from the main home page before following the login anchor and I can retrieve it in Firefox from the Storage Inspector or by examining request headers in the Network tab from the Developer Tools. Since the Storage Inspector labels this cookie as `HttpOnly`, I cannot retrieve it with `document.cookie`.

A trivial

```
curl -I 'https://someweb.com/home.do'
```

outputs the `JSESSIONID` cookie, so I tried to fetch the home page releasing the cookie:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://someweb.com/login.do/home.do", false);
request.send();
request.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

but the cookie is still not shown.

I've tried using `GM_xmlHttpRequest` with various userscript managers and getting `responseHeaders` from the `Response` object, but the `JSSESSIONID` cookie wasn't there.

I know `HttpOnly` cookies are not exposed to JavaScript to avoid the injection of malicious scripts. However, it shouldn't be so for userscripts, which are run by extensions (therefore trusted by the browser) and there should be a way to fill my credentials without a manual copy and paste.

Comment: @double-beep: Tampermonkey is a closed source that I would rather avoid. At this point the best option is to create a simple extension.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but only in [Tampermonkey Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey-beta/gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf) using `GM_cookie` (see: [docs with types and examples](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_cookie.list)). [Violentmonkey](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey/issues/603) and [Greasemonkey](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1802) do not support anything similar.

You should use `GM_cookie.list(details, callback)`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Overflow Question 65749907
// @version     0.1
// @include     https://someweb.com/login.do
// @run-at      document-end
// @grant       GM_cookie
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const cookieName = 'JSESSIONID';
    const urlToFetch = 'https://someweb.com/login.do'

    GM_cookie.list(
        { url: urlToFetch, name: cookieName },
        (cookie, error) => {
            if (!error) console.log(cookie[0]);
            else console.error(error);
        }
    );
})();
```

This searches for a cookie names `cookieName` in `urlToFetch`. You can only access cookies on the URLs the script is allowed to run - otherwise, you'll get an error.

To set or delete a cookie, you should use `GM_cookie.set()` or `GM_cookie.delete()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If yow backend injected the cookie all you need to do is on yow request set the `withCredentials: true`:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: I tried, but while the output of `curl -I 'HOMEPAGE'` includes a `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=...` line, if executing your code with my URL and adding `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`, I just get:
`"connection: close

content-encoding: gzip

content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

date: Sat, 16 Jan 2021 14:33:22 GMT

server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

transfer-encoding: chunked

vary: Accept-Encoding

"`